# How to create mapping of composed object with Hibernate when using a complex sqlquery?

Tags: java, hibernate, nativequery

I am trying to use the below query with Hibernate's session.createSQLQuery.
The Entity object corresponding to **user** has an attribute called **address**.
The ***address*** object is created out of **5 fields from table 'user'**.
If I do not use an SQLQuery it gets filled auto-magically. 
However without the SQLQuery I can't get all the info I would get from the desired joins shown below. 
The user entity object also attributes like accessPlan which I am filling up using

```
.addEntity("accessPlan", AccessPlan.class)
```

Query:

```
SELECT 
    user.*, 
    ap.*,
    country.*,
    auth.*, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(coup.code SEPARATOR ' ') coupons
FROM 
    user
    INNER JOIN access_plan ap ON (user.access_plan = ap.id)
    INNER JOIN country ON (user.country=country.code)
    LEFT JOIN user_auth auth ON (user.id = auth.userid)
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT 
                    trans.user_id,coupon.code
        FROM 
                    payments_transaction AS trans
        INNER JOIN payments_coupon coupon ON (trans.payments_coupon_id=coupon.id)
    ) coup ON (user.id=coup.user_id)    
GROUP BY user.id;
```

What can be the easiest way to fill up the composed ***address*** object while using the SQLQuery? 
***OR***
Is there a way to avoid using SQLQuery for a query like this?

Comment: BTW the result of this query should be a List<User>.
I am using 

    .setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(User.class))

to convert each record to User object

Comment: Btw .. the atuo-magic part was actually the use of the @Embeddable annotation.

Answer (score 0):

Please check below example from the section '[Returning multiple entities](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querysql.html#d0e13763)'

```
String sql = "SELECT ID as {c.id}, NAME as {c.name}, " + 
     "BIRTHDATE as {c.birthDate}, MOTHER_ID as {c.mother}, {mother.*} " +
     "FROM CAT_LOG c, CAT_LOG m WHERE {c.mother} = c.ID";

List loggedCats = sess.createSQLQuery(sql)
    .addEntity("cat", Cat.class)
    .addEntity("mother", Cat.class).list()
```

In your case, cat = user, mother = address... somewhat like that.

I do not have anything to try out at the moment but I guess this will help.